# R: Equivalent for Sumif and Countif by Categorical variable across columns in R

Tags: r, group-by, countif, sumifs

Say I have a data set with 10 columns . Of which 9 are numeric and one is categorical with values like HIgh Medium and Low. I want to summarise ( similar to sumif and countif in excel)  by the categorical variable across all the 9 numeric columns in R.

How can this be done? I am pretty new to R and any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: this is aggregation, in R there is `aggregate`, `table`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data frame is called `df` and your categorical variable is called `group.var`, then you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(group.var) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(n(),sum))
```

Example with built-in `iris` data frame:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(n(), sum))

     Species Sepal.Length_n Sepal.Width_n Petal.Length_n Petal.Width_n Sepal.Length_sum Sepal.Width_sum Petal.Length_sum Petal.Width_sum
      (fctr)          (int)         (int)          (int)         (int)            (dbl)           (dbl)            (dbl)           (dbl)
1     setosa             50            50             50            50            250.3           171.4             73.1            12.3
2 versicolor             50            50             50            50            296.8           138.5            213.0            66.3
3  virginica             50            50             50            50            329.4           148.7            277.6           101.3
```

There are many other options (e.g., the `data.table` package, and base R solutions using `tapply`, `aggregate`, etc.)

Comment: I keep getting Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’ even after I have succesfully installed the package from Cran. Any tip on this?

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know the base R idioms for these types of operations before moving on to the bewildering array of packages (useful as they may be).

```
by(iris, iris$Species, summary)
```

will split a data.frame and apply a function to each subset. If you need to operate on a vector rather than a data.frame, see `?tapply`.

```
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, summary)
```